# MySQL: Exclusive lock

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql error and I didn't find the answer till now on the internet: "Wait on a lock was aborted due to a pending exclusive lock"
I have a lot of transaction in the same time. These based on an innodb table, that has a few triggers. These triggers read and write other innodb and myisam tables.
I know what is the "wait lock", but I don't have enough information about "exclusive lock". What should I do to terminate this error, because these transactions are not finishing and not updateing the rows in the this table.

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard and a MySQL 5.6.15 on it. The database is on an SSD drive and the logs are on a simple HDD.

This is my ini file:

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
basedir="C:/MySQL/mysql-5.6.15-winx64/"
datadir="C:/DB/myCustomer/data"
innodb_data_home_dir="C:/DB/myCustomer/innodb/"
log-bin = "E:/Log/mysqldblog/myCustomer/mysql-bin/log"
log-error = "E:/Log/mysqldblog/myCustomer/errorlog/error"
tmpdir ="E:/MySQLTEMP/"
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
join_buffer_size = 4M
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
max_allowed_packet = 100M
tmp_table_size=64M
max_heap_table_size=64M
innodb_log_file_size    = 256M
innodb_thread_concurrency   = 16
federated=1
default-storage-engine=INNODB
event-scheduler = ON
max_sp_recursion_depth = 50
character-set-server=utf8
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 
binlog_format=mixed
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
log-warnings = 0
```

I would apprisiate if somebody could help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advence.

kind regards,
András

Answer (score 0):

Exclusive locks are described in MySQL [glossary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_exclusive_lock):

> A kind of lock that prevents any other transaction from locking the same row. Depending on the transaction isolation level, this kind of lock might block other transactions from writing to the same row, or might also block other transactions from reading the same row. The default InnoDB isolation level, REPEATABLE READ, enables higher concurrency by allowing transactions to read rows that have exclusive locks, a technique known as consistent read.

We cannot tell you how to avoid specifically this instance of the error, we can only provide generic guidance on how to debug it and what MySQL settings may help you to reduce the risk of receiving such errors. The specific solution may require restructuring your data, or changing the application logic, or even upscaling your hw - you have to make the call.

To debug the error, use [SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-standard-monitor.html) statement (from MySQL v5.7.4 use [innodb information_schema tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-i_s-tables.html) instead, but the question is applicable to v5.6).

Under the `LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK` section you will find information on what transactions and statements caused the deadlock.

Out of the dozens of MySQL settings, [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) has the most direct impact on these kind of errors, since you can give more time to MySQL to wait until the situation is resolved. However, you need to be careful because increasing this timeout setting may lead to slowing down of your application and may simply mask the issues your application is facing.

Sok szerencsét!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I looked for these things but I have no result. The problem occured unpredictable.
Could you tell me what is the difference between the "lock wait timeout" and "Wait on a lock was aborted due to a pending exclusive lock"?
Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, the 1st is a server system variable (a config setting), the 2nd is an error message. Not even the same category. What exactly did you try to ask with this question?

Comment: I have tried to ask, what is the difference when I found a “Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction” error message and the "Wait on a lock was aborted due to a pending exclusive lock" error message?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the answer to this question.